# Get Magento Session from Zend framework (Another Application)

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I want to get the Magento Session From Zend Framework (Another application). I need that the application in Zend Framework validates if the user in the admin is logged (Magento). I have the following code in my Zend Framework application :

```
    // Initialize Magento
    include_once 'C:/xampp/htdocs/mymagento/app/Mage.php';

    // Initialize Magento
    Mage::app('default');

    // This initalizes the session, using 'adminhtml' as the session name.
    // Just ignore the returned Mage_Core_Model_Session instance
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));

    // Get a singleton instance of the Mage_Admin_Model_Session class
    // This is just the 'admin' namespace of the current session. (adminhtml in this case)
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');


    // Use the 'admin/session' object to check loggedIn status
    if ( $session->isLoggedIn() ) {
        echo "logged in";
    } else {
        echo "not logged in";
    }
```

The response is allways "not logged in"; when i'm logged in Magento Backend.

Answer (score 0):

The session is created for the parent domain only - the one Magento is launched from.

I assume that in your case Magento and "another zend app" are different domains, which may be triggering the issue. Both Magento and "another zend app" should be on one parent domains. E.g.:

(*.example.com | magento.example.com | anotherzendapp.example.com).

Another reason why this issue occurs is the autoload by another zend app. If this is the case, this solution should help:

```
$autoloaders = spl_autoload_functions();
$anotherZendApp = $autoloaders[0];
spl_autoload_unregister($anotherZendApp);

// YOU CODE

restore_error_handler();
restore_exception_handler();
spl_autoload_register($anotherZendApp);
```